# Как подключиться к Odoo, которая стоит либо на Google cloud platform, либо на AWS.

Tags: amazon, облако, amazon-web-services, google-cloud

Выбрал инстанс с Ubuntu 14... подтянул postgresql, подтянул Odoo из github. Настроил через gitbash, подключившись через -ssh, подготовился к запуску и встал. Вот 2 алгоритма, по которым я делал [алгоритм 1](http://devdrive.ru/post/Odoo:Installation/), [алгоритм 2](http://osc.dondub.com/articles/2015/03/article_833). Соответсвенно всего я развернул на 4 инстансах. Я новичок, мой вопрос покажется очень простым.
Как мне подключиться через браузер к удалённому серверу на AWS и GCP? 
Пробовал вводить `DNS IP` и `Public IP` и создал `Elastic IP`. Всёравно зайти не могу. 
Пробовал прописывать `public ip:8069`.
Что я делаю не так. Не может быть на разных облачных серверах одинаковая ошибка в правилах подключения. У меня Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня возникла такая же проблема - как оказалось в windows firewall на инстансе AWS был отключен Network discovery и заблокирован порт 8069.

Доступность сервера можно проверить пингом.

В Ubuntu тоже видимо где-то что-то блокируется, попробуйте в этом направлении посмотреть.

Comment: Просто нужно было разблокировать порт 8069. Из-за незнания, я делал это кривым путём и разблокировал совсем другой тип порта.

Answer (score 1):

Делаем так:

```
apt-get install nginx
vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Затем в конфиге `nginx` находим `location /` и пишем что-то вроде:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069
```

Как показывает практика - это лучший способ общения с `odoo`. Выставлять его портом `8069` наружу - опасно. Он использует `werkzeug` для обработки запросов, и вполне себе дырявый (версия `0.11` на момент написания ответа), а в виду консервативности - security updates в дистрибутив `odoo` приходят не часто.

Comment: Сделал, как исходя из пункта выше. Теперь у меня открывается страница ngnix при обычном вводе ip. Если ввожу public ip:8069 - пустая страница.

Comment: @RadoDuoistin, nginx должен проксировать запросы с `location /` на порт `8069`. Никак не показывать обычную страницу. Выполните `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в разделе ec2 в Security Groups и откройте там порт 80 и 443 в той группе которая подключена к инстансу.

Comment: Не вышло. Всёравно не подключается. Порты открыл.